# how create a sequence of random number

Tags: random, numbers, generator, sequence

I wrote this code to generate a sequence of random number but this program give me the same random number:

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

   for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
       srand((unsigned)time(0));
       cout<<"\t"<<rand();
    }
  getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

the output is a sequence with equal number how i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only call `srand()` once, outside the loop, before using rand().  Try:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  srand((unsigned)time(0)); // Only call once.

  for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    cout<<"\t"<<rand();
  }

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```